# Angular UI for a WebAPI in .NET Core while still the primary purpose is a WebAPI, not a frontend App

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Any feedback much appreciated.

I need to create a Web API (ASP.NET Core Web API), which does some basic CRUD operations. Thats no issue at all, and I need to create a simple Angular UI for the Web API as well. Thats also no issue. But is there a way to combine both into a single application ? WebAPI mainly and an optional UI part in Angular than having a second angular solution ? I know there is a visual studio project template where you create a .NET Core Angular Application, if I do that, how would I expose the API at the sametime to other clients as API, while still managing the Angular UI ?

Put in another way, my .NET Core application should be primarily a WebAPI which should work independently and act like a WebAPI, while an optional part of it should have an Angular frontend connecting to the WebAPI.

Comment: All you have to do is compile your angular project and put it under wwwroot.  Then you can navigate to your index.html page, set your webapi startup to serve static files and your done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed [@johnny's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017930/angular-ui-for-a-webapi-in-net-core-while-still-the-primary-purpose-is-a-webapi/60336770#comment106152975_60017930) and it works !

> All you have to do is compile your angular project and put it under wwwroot.  Then you can navigate to your index.html page, set your webapi startup to serve static files and your done

Answer (score 0):

You can view this as a matter of security for your WebAPI and how you expose connections to it. You can serve your API endpoints under one route, i.e. /api and you Angular application at you site route or host it elsewhere.

If you follow the same practices for exposing the WebAPI cross origin, then your Angular application can consume the API in exactly the same way as any other client would.